# Winsock shutdown and closesocket on socket timeout

Tags: c, timeout, winsock

I have a `SOCKET` variable which is part of a custom `struct`. The `SOCKET` variable is filled after an `accept` call.
A call to `select` is then performed on the SOCKET to detect data coming from the other end. The `select` is invoked with a timeout and returns `0` indicating that a client connected but no data was received and a timeout has been reached.

I normally call `shutdown` and then `closesocket` on a `SOCKET` variable however when a connection reaches a timeout after the invocation of `select` the application sometimes crashes when the structure which contains the `SOCKET` variable is freed.

This is a sample of the whole code (I intentionally omitted some checks to make the code easy to read):

```
int result;
int size;
fd_set fdset;
SOCKET sock;
SOCKET serversock;
struct sockaddr *address_info;
struct mystruct *ms;
...
//Create and initialize server socket
size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(serversock, address_info, size);
...
//Accept client connections
ms = calloc(1, sizeof(struct mystruct) );
sock = accept(serversock, address_info, &size);
ms->sock = sock;
result = select( (int)(sock + 1), &fdset, NULL, NULL, timeout);

if(result == 0) {
    
    //Handle timeout
    ...
    shutdown(ms->sock, SD_BOTH);
    closesocket(ms->sock);
}

//Free the memory
free(ms) <-------------- CRASH HERE !
```

NOTE: The crash only happens if a timeout is detected.

So the question is: can the invocation of `shutdown` and `closesocket` cause a crash if they are called after a timeout ?

Comment: shutdown will block communication with the socket in either read, write or both. While close will just destroy the socket. But you haven't posted any code? See [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The code is not simple there are a lot of other stuff which are called in between each function but I can try to paste a kind of sample.

Comment: The issue with the code pasted is I can't see anything that would cause a crash, the reason I asked for a minimal reproducible example is typically if you're capable of isolating the problem, a lot of the time you can actually spot the issue yourself. Or realise the error isn't where you think it might be. But I am wondering, is this running on multiple threads or a single thread?

Comment: @Yuumi the code which handle a client connection and its communication with the server run on a single thread. It is not meant for multiple client connections. The main question was can the invocation of  shutdown and closesocket after a timeout cause a crash ? If I understood correctly you said "no" so probably the problem is elsewhere. I believe it worth posting an answer specifying that it is completely legal to invoke   shutdown and closesocket after a timeout.

Comment: "*can the invocation of shutdown and closesocket cause a crash if they are called after a timeout ?*" - no, they cannot.  So, there must be a bug elsewhere in code we can't see that is messing up the memory you are trying to free.

Answer (score 1):

Calling shutdown then close on a socket after a timeout is perfectly legal and will not result in a crash. In fact that is how you should handle the socket. The call to free which results in a crash seems to be an isolated problem. It could have to do with re-accessing of the structure once it's been free'd or calling free on the same region of memory multiple times. With the code you provided I can not see why calling free would result in a crash although I can not see what the structure looks like and do not have a Minimal Reproducible Compilable example to go off of.